# How to make a CocoaPods project work on OS X El Capitan & Xcode 7 Beta?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

I've updated to OS X El Capitan & Xcode 7 Beta released today and now my CocoaPods projects no longer work because of the new Swift syntax requirements. The automated Xcode project update breaks the code. Has anyone already figured this out already? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until Cocoapods supports Swift 2, at the very least you should be able to continue to use Xcode 6 until it does. If Xcode 7 has stomped all over your Cocoapods already, this link shows you how to clean it up https://gist.github.com/mbinna/4202236.

Basically, from inside any project using Cocoapods:

```
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update
```

Then rebuild using Xcode 6 and everything should be back to normal.

Comment: CocoaPods is not tied to any particular Swift version and thus this explanation is incorrect. The actual problem is with the Pods you are using,  these will need to be updated for the updated Swift syntax.

Answer (score 105):

It worked for me for the bug when run Cocoapods on El Capitan 10.11 following [this guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#sudo-less-installation):

```
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH

gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Thanks! This works to get cocoapods working on 10.11/El Capitan at all due to the 'features' added by SIP (http://arstechnica.co.uk/apple/2015/09/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-the-ars-technica-review/8/#h1).

A straight 'sudo gem install cocoapods' tries to install to /usr/bin which is no longer writeable _even to root_

Comment: While it's actually not the answer to the original question, it really helped me solve the Pods problem in El Capitan, thanks mate!

Comment: sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin       run this after that

Comment: @CanAksoy I don't need to use your command, it still work. What does it mean? Is it better?

Comment: @huync I can't solve without chmod. try chmod, if 'gem install' did not solve your problem.

Comment: @huync Awesome dude. Works and saved me some valuable time. Upvote!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, please help. I still get 'Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0) in any repository' error. Just upgraded to OSX 10.11.4 form Yosemite

Answer (score 6):

I did this to make it work for me:

```
brew install ruby
/usr/local/bin/gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Yes,  updating Cocoapods helped. Seems that Cocoapods now supports Xcode7

Answer (score 0):

Disabling system integrity protection worked for me.

Follow these steps to disable SIP:

Restart your Mac.
Before OS X starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.
From the Utilities menu, select Terminal.
At the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return: csrutil disable
Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.
From the  menu, select Restart